# How to insert values in database from Adapter class to fragment dialog class?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I created an adapter class in which

> onClick method I'm calling a DialogFragment extended class like

```
 if (!item.getNext().equals("0")) {
     fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
     AddonDialogFragment postalFragment = AddonDialogFragment.newInstance(Integer.valueOf(item.getNext()));
     postalFragment.show(fragmentManager, "AddonDialogFragment");
  }
```

I'm calling here a fragment dialog class. In **Adapter class** I made one interface. my interface code is also working fine but when i'm trying to insert data in **sqlite database** , my code is not working.

```
 @Override
public void getItemFromAddon(String addonName, String addonId, String addonPrice) {
    dbInsert(addonName, addonPrice, addonId, hashmapHead);

} 


 public void dbInsert(String addonName,String addonPrice,String addonId,String hashmapHead){
    Log.e(TAG, "dbInsert: " );
    databaseHelper = new CartDatabaseHelper(getContext());
    databaseHelper.setAddons(addonName, addonPrice, addonId, hashmapHead);
    Log.e(TAG, "getItemFromAddon: " + addonName + "  " + addonId + "  " + addonPrice + "  " + hashmapHead);

}
```

In log i'm successfully getting **dbInsert** but after that code is not working.
Can any one please tell me what is the error or did i mistaken anywhere?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: What is there error? can you add logcat?

Comment: actually i din't get any error. Only that line of code is not working

Comment: after printing **Log.e(TAG, "dbInsert: " );**  next line is not working without any error or any log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In databaseHelper I was getting null value. When I debug my program i got that. Simply defined the object **static** and got what I was looking for.

```
static MyDatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
```

and in onCreate method

```
databaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(getContext());
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe when you call `databaseHelper = new CartDatabaseHelper(getContext());` the getContext() returns null. Can you post your code of CartDatabaseHelper?